# how can I parse a string like this (6,8)

Tags: c, parsing, segmentation-fault

I want to parse a string in a format as (6,8), and I want to store 6 and 8 in different variable. I'm trying to use the "strtok". However it gives me a segfault

here is my code

```
 int main()
{
char a[80]="(6,8)";
parsing(a);

return 0;
}

int parsing(char* a)
{
char* word;
char temp[80] ;
stpcpy(temp,a);
char* new;
char **newendptr=NULL;
char **newnewendptr=NULL;

    int u,v;    
    word= strtok(temp, "(");
    word= strtok(NULL, ",");

    u=strtoumax(secword,newendptr,0);
    printf("%d\n",u);

    new= strtok(NULL, ")");
    printf("%s\n",new);

    v=strtoumax(new,newnewendptr,0);
    printf("%d %d",u,v);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You're supposed to declare the `endptr` as `char *endptr;` and then pass the address of `endptr` to `strtoumax`, eg. `u=strtoumax(word,&endptr,0);`

Comment: @user3386109 yes, if you want to use the result, but there's nothing wrong with how the OP has written it.  Except it's obtuse and confusing.  That's not why it's crashing.  I would recommend they simply attach a debugger and step through the code.  As currently written, this program wouldn't even compile.

Comment: `word= strtok(NULL, ",");` : `word` is  `NULL`.

Comment: Using `strtoumax()` and assigning the result to an `int` is a bit less than obvious — it throws away error indications, at any rate.  But then, so does passing a null as the second argument to `strtoumax()`.

Comment: *"... there's nothing wrong with how the OP has written it. Except it's obtuse and confusing"* LOL, I'd say that's something wrong with it. But I agree that since the OP doesn't seem to care about the result, he could just pass `NULL`.

Comment: You try to parse `secword` but you neither declare nor initialize it.

Comment: `word= strtok(temp, "()");
    word= strtok(word, ",");
    u=strtoumax(word,NULL,0);`

Comment: @user3386109: Argh!  Bother — looking at the wrong line of output.  Yes, I got `6,8)` for the reason you stated.  I'm glad I prevaricated a little — but not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It pays to read the specification of [`strtok()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok.html) carefully.

This code works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

static int parsing(char *a)
{
    char temp[80];
    strcpy(temp, a);

    printf("temp 0 = %p [[%s]]\n", (void *)temp, temp);
    char *word1 = strtok(temp, "(,)");
    printf("word 1 = %p [[%s]]\n", (void *)word1, word1 == 0 ? "<nothing>" : word1);
    char *word2 = strtok(NULL, "(,)");
    printf("word 2 = %p [[%s]]\n", (void *)word2, word2 == 0 ? "<nothing>" : word2);

    int u = strtoumax(word1, 0, 0);
    int v = strtoumax(word2, 0, 0);
    printf("%d %d\n", u, v);
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    char a[80] = "(6,8)";
    parsing(a);
    return 0;
}
```

The output on my machine is:

```
temp 0 = 0x7fff54844440 [[(6,8)]]
word 1 = 0x7fff54844441 [[6]]
word 2 = 0x7fff54844443 [[8]]
6 8
```

The problem is that the call to `strtok()` in the original with `"("` as delimiter skips over the opening `(`, but then doesn't find another to mark the end of the token, so the rest of the string is consumed.  The second call to `strtok()` therefore has nothing to process and returns NULL.

The fixed code avoids that problem.  The initial delimiter must include `(` to skip that, and must include `,` to stop there.  The second delimiter should include `)`; the other characters are not strictly needed.

Since you aren't inspecting the output pointer that's the second argument to `strtoumax()`, it may as well be NULL (aka `0`) each time.  Using `strtoumax()` and assigning the result to an `int` is a little odd.  With the given data, it is OK, but more generally, it risks losing important information.  The `strtoX()` functions are quite powerful but also remarkably delicate in how they report out of bounds values, etc.  This usage throws away all that information (and you'd need to set `errno` to 0 before calling it, and you'd have to save the values in `uintmax_t` variables, to get and preserve the information accurately).

In this context, a more succinct (but not necessarily simpler) way to parse the input string would be:

```
char c;
if (sscanf(a, " (%d ,%d %c", &u, &v, &c) != 3 || c != ')')
    …oops — malformatted data…
```

Make sure you know why the spaces are present and why they are where they are.  That may require careful scrutiny of the POSIX specification for [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html).  You can decide to do without the spaces; you need to know what the consequences of doing so are.  If you want to be sure that the whole string was parsed, use:

```
char c;
int n;
if (sscanf(a, " (%d ,%d %c%n", &u, &v, &c, &n) != 3 || c != ')' || temp[n] != '\0')
    …Oops…
```

Note that `%n` conversion specifications are not counted so the 3 does not change.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by @Jonathan Leffler seems to have covered what was not working in your original code nicely. I just thought that I would add a solution that will parse strings containing n-tuples of unknown length. Here, the `parsing()` function takes as arguments an address of a pointer to `int`, which is where a simulated array of numbers will be stored, and an input string, which should be formatted as `"(int1, int2, ...)"`. I make no promises about the behavior of this function with malformed input. The function allocates space, stores the numbers in the simulated array, and returns the number of numbers found.

I included a function to display the parsed numbers, and even wrapped the call to `realloc()` in a function to catch allocation errors. I also added a few more examples to show how it responds to some different inputs. Of course, since my version of `parsing()` allocates memory, the caller is responsible for freeing it.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t parsing(int **nums, char *a);
void * xrealloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
void shownums(int *nums, size_t n);

int main(void)
{
    int *nums = NULL;
    size_t n;
    char a[80] = "(6, 8)";
    char b[80] = "(2, 3, 5)";
    char c[80] = "(7)";
    char d[80] = "(11,)";
    char e[80] = "(2, 7, 1, 8, 2, 8, 1, 8, 2, 8, 5)";

    n = parsing(&nums, a);
    shownums(nums, n);

    n = parsing(&nums, b);
    shownums(nums, n);

    n = parsing(&nums, c);
    shownums(nums, n);

    n = parsing(&nums, d);
    shownums(nums, n);

    n = parsing(&nums, e);
    shownums(nums, n);

    /* Free allocated memory */
    free(nums);

    return 0;
}

size_t parsing(int **nums, char *a)
{
    size_t nums_sz = 0;
    char *res;

    while ((res = strtok(a, "(,)"))) {
        nums_sz++;
        *nums = realloc(*nums, sizeof(int) * nums_sz);
        (*nums)[nums_sz - 1] = atoi(res);
        a = NULL;
    }

    return nums_sz;
}

void * xrealloc(void *ptr, size_t size)
{
    void *ret = realloc(ptr, size);
    if (ret == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return ret;
}

void shownums(int *nums, size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", nums[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}
```

And here is the output:

```
6 8 
2 3 5 
7 
11 
2 7 1 8 2 8 1 8 2 8 5
```